# How can I solely use external authentication with asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I would like to solely use external authentication (Microsoft) with Asp.Net core Identity. The default Individual User Accounts - web application includes the option to create local accounts. When you register using for example Microsoft, it will still ask you for an email address and offer you the ability to set a password.

How can I disable the options to change the email address and set a password and only use Microsoft as external authentication provider?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is that you can [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) and remove the code you don't want.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1824) is the discussion about similar topic .